# NullPointerException only when on Google Play Store?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I recently uploaded an update of my app to Google Play. When trying it out, I get an error when clicking on a manually added banner (e.g. not AdMob or anything like that). The click is setting of an `AsyncTask` that sends data to a php-script using POST. I use ProGuard so when I send the error report to myself I am only able to see the method in which the error is caused: doInBackground. I am also able to see that it is a `NullPointerException`. The strange thing is, when I run the app on my device from my computer using Eclipse, the error doesn't occur, so I can't really find what line is causing the `NullPointerException`. It has worked perfectly in previous versions of my app, and I haven't made any changes to this code. And when I look through the method `doInBackground`, I can't find any place where a `NullPointerException` might occur.

Here is the error message from my developers console, this is proguarded though:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:278)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:208)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at se.nollekollen.main.d.a(Unknown Source)
at se.nollekollen.main.d.doInBackground(Unknown Source)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
... 5 more
```

And here is my doInBackground:

```
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
    String url_stats = "http://xxxxx.xx/statistik/sendStatistics_click.php";

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("activity", getClass().getEnclosingClass().getName().substring(20)));
    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("section", SECTION));

    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url_stats);

    try {
        httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

The only thing that could be null here is actually "SECTION", but that wouldn't cause a `NullPointerException` since the value can be null when creating a new BasicNameValuePair(key, value).

Can anyone find what could cause the `NullPointerException`? And how is it possible that this ONLY occurs when the app is downloaded from Google Play, and not when run from the computer?

Comment: Post the exact error message.

Comment: Alright, I added it :)

Comment: proguard creates a mapping file where you are able to create useful stacktraces from the unreadable again

Comment: Can I access that mapping file even though the app isn't run from the computer? The error only occurs when I have downloaded the app from Google Play, not when run from the computer

Comment: Well the mapping file only helped me figure out in which method the error occured, and that I already knew, so that isn't of any help really. What I can't understand is how I haven't changed anything and it hasn't been a problem until now, and also how it's possible that this error only occurs when the app is exported to an apk-file and uploaded to Google Play, not when run from Eclipse?

Comment: I am calling this very same method in several activities, since I have the same banner showing on all of them. In all activities but one this error occurs, and there is no difference what so ever in the code of the method, nor how they get called. This is so weird I don't know what to do? :S

Comment: I'm wondering if proguard is breaking some stage of the getClass().getEnclosingClass().getName() sequence - can you log that one method at a time from left to right?  You should not have to upload to google play, you can uninstall your development apk and adb install (or email yourself) the file you prepared for uploading, and it should have the same result.

Comment: Hmm, I removed the proguard-folder and commented out the line in project.properties, then exported a new APK and did an adb-install. But the methods and classes are still called a, b, c, d... etc. Is there a more proper way to remove proguard? I've googled it and that's the way most people seem to do it